# awk or sed: Best way to grab [this text]

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I'm trying to parse various info from log files, some of which is placed within square brackets. For example:

```
Tue, 06 Nov 2007 10:04:11 INFO     processor:receive: [someuserid], [somemessage]  msgtype=[T]
```

What's an elegant way to grab 'someuserid' from these lines, using sed, awk, or other unix utility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix))** 
 use it like this: `cut -f2 -d[ | cut -f1 -d]`

```
bart@hal9k:~> YOURTEXT="Tue, 06 Nov 2007 10:04:11 INFO     processor:receive: [someuserid], [somemessage]  msgtype=[T]"
bart@hal9k:~> SOMEID=`echo $YOURTEXT | cut -f2 -d[ | cut -f1 -d]`
bart@hal9k:~> echo $SOMEID
someuserid
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of cut. Works beautifully.

Comment: yeah, it so basic, yet ppl forget about it's existence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with *all* the bracketed fields, I'd use Perl:

```
perl -lne '
    my @fields = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
    # do something with @fields, like:
    print join(":", @fields);
' logfile ...
```

Answer (score 0):

using bash shell

```
while read -r line
do
   case "$line" in
        *processor*receive* ) 
            t=${line#*[}
            echo ${t%%]*}
            ;;
   esac
done < "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/INFO/{s/.[^[]*\[//;s/\].*//p}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK:

```
cat file | awk -F[\]\[] '{print $2}'
```

I have found that multiple delimiters do not work in some older versions of AWK. If it doesn't, you can use two awks:

```
cat file | awk -F[ '{print $2}' | awk -F] '{print $1}'
```